# iScroll makes others onclick stop working on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, iscroll

I'm working on a HTML-based app for my iPhone 5s which basically is a app with 3 images next to eachother (where only one of them is visible, but the next one is shown using swiping gestures and so on).

To get the horizontal scrolling I used iScroll which does the job very nice, but makes another JavaScript fail while tested on the phone.

The other JavaScript is making the last picture change when you click on it, "flipping" the picture to another one, but has since the scroller was added stopped working.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

```
<script language="javascript">
function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/05/20/FABIANISELLf9adc.jpg") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/05/20/studentkortbak.jpg";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/05/20/FABIANISELLf9adc.jpg";
    }
}
```

### Don't think this is used but either way, maybe this is the problem somehow:

```
<script> function BlockMove(event) {
 //Makes the website act like a app, NOSCROLL
  event.preventDefault() ;
 }
```

**And the probably most interesting code:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="scroller">
    <ul>
        <li><img alt="" src="first.png" style="width: 320px;" /></li>
        <li><img alt="" src="second.png" style="width: 320px;"/></li>
        <li><p>
    <img alt="" src="another.jpg" 
        style="width: 320px; margin-top: 3px;" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />
</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try enabling the tap option in iScroll, and have your current click event bind to that instead. You can enable the tap by adding the option in the second parameter of the iScroll constructor, like this: `var scroller = new IScroll('#wrapper', { tap: true });`You then bind to the tap event as you would any other event. From the iScroll documentation:

> options.tap
>
> Set this to true to let iScroll emit a custom tapevent when the scroll area is clicked/tapped but not scrolled.
>
> This is the suggested way to handle user interaction with clickable elements. To listen to the tap event you would add an event listener as you would do for a standard event. Example:
>
> element.addEventListener('tap', doSomething, false); \ Native $('#element').on('tap', doSomething); \ jQuery
>
> You can also customize the event name by passing a string. Eg:
>
> tap: 'myCustomTapEvent'
>
> In this case you'd listen to myCustomTapEvent.

http://iscrolljs.com/

So, in practise, your HTML page would be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script> <!-- set to correct path to your JS file-->

</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img alt="" src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="width: 320px;" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img alt="" src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="width: 320px;" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>
            <img alt="" src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="width: 320px; margin-top: 3px;" id="imgClickAndChange" />
          </p>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and then in your javascript file:

```
  function changeImage() {
    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "image1.jpg") {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "image2.jpg";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "image1.jpg";
    }
}

function init(){
    //Do iScroll constructor with tap: true
    
    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").addEventListener('tap', changeImage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Since i'm prett ynew to this and self learned, I don't really know how to "bind to tap event" to be honest...

The only place I can find somewhere where it could fit, is in the second code (second code-box in my original post).

Sorry, but where should I put it?
Thank you...!

Comment: You can add an onload attribute to your body tag in the HTML. This would have a value of the function to be called which will in turn, do the event binding. The function would reside in a separate JavaScript file preferably, but can be a script tag on the page (JavaScript file is best practice)

Comment: This is the "click" code im using at the moment:

Don't really know how to connect the "tap" event to this... Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

https://jsfiddle.net/d1eok0dp/2/

Comment: I couldn't get what I was trying to convey across in jsFiddle, but i have updated my answer with the HTML and js

Comment: It works now!!! Thank you so much for your help. Time to learn some more about "events" which I obviously wasn't so good at.
Thank you!!!